# Having dynamic pagenames in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I just wonder how i can make dynamic pages in `Laravel 5`? I know this has properbly been asked before, however i couldn't find any questions/answers matching exactly what i need.

I'm building a CMS for myself in Laravel and i want to be able to dynamically generate new pages (stored in the database).
How can i make dynamic routes, to match url's with pagenames?

eg: `domain.com/{URL}` where `{URL}` is the page, retrieved from the database storage.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [route parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters) in the laravel docs, and [this chapter](http://daylerees.com/codebright-advanced-routing/) of code bright.